# Background image not showing in some phones

Tags: css

Everything works fine for some phones, but when I tested it for example on HTC the background image isn't showing.

CSS

```
header {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)), url(../images/lets-get-down-to-business.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
  background-position: center;
}
```

and the only query that touches the BG image

```
@media only screen and (max-height:600px){
  header {
    height: 600px;   
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated with explanation.

Thank You!

Comment: Best guess is - old browsers do not support `linear-gradient`, use only background image if you need to, as well as `vh` you'll find out another way to do it.

Comment: can you try background-size:auto 100%; just tell me what happens after that.

Comment: Can you specify HTC?

Comment: Yeah it was the Linear Gradient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that this is because whatever browser you are using on the HTC does not support the linear-gradient CSS function.

[Gradients compatibility - mobile](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/images/gradients_mobile.html)

It seems to me that the stock android browser doesn't support this yet.

That's where I would start though, you might be able to just change the syntax a little and get it to work.